# How do you include external libraries into Haxe?

Tags: c++, haxe

I'm trying to write a program for which I would like to use some external C++ libraries in Haxe. I can't really figure it out since the official documentation is old (http://old.haxe.org/doc/cpp/ffi) and I'm not familiar with C++ either.

So how do you do that in Haxe? I suppose I'll need to install `hxcpp` via `haxelib`, but that's about as much as I know.

Answer (score 2):

For a start, check out [C++ Magic by Hugh Sanderson](http://haxe.io/roundups/wwx/c++-magic/). Much of the mentioned Compiler Metadata in that talk can be found at the [Built-in Compiler Metadata](http://haxe.org/manual/cr-metadata.html) page in the Haxe Manual.

> He then talks briefly about metadata magic. He provides metadata for classes and functions. For classes you have the following:
>
> ```
> @:headerClassCode(...) which injects member variables and inline functions.
> @:headerCode(...) which includes external headers.
> @:headerNamespaceCode(...) which allows you to add to the global namespace.
> @:cppFileCode(...) which allows you to include external headers only in C++ files.
> @:cppNamespaceCode(...) which implements static variables.
> @:buildXml(...) which allows you to add to the build.xml file.
> ```
>
> For function metadata you get the following:
>
> ```
> @:functionCode(...)
> @:functionTailCode(...)
> ```
>
> Hugh states these are largely redundant as you should use untyped
>   __cpp_(...) instead.